# Apache Derby - Embedded Mode - Failed to start database while reloading a servlet

Tags: servlets, derby

I am using an embedded apache derby database on file system within a servlet application installed on a Tomcat 6.

Unfortunately I have almost no control over the tomcat configuration and other servlet installation and I cannot use the network/server mode for derby.

I have a minor issue whenever the servlet is reloaded (e.g. for debug purposes), i.e. the database seems to stay locked or in use by the old thread/servlet instance and the new one initialized by the Tomcat.

My application tries to open/create the database and it's working fine unless, as I said, I reload the servlet. This seems to happen because no methods are called whenever the tomcat reload the servlet and I have no time to shutdown the database connection from the correct thread, and when I try to start a new connection on the reloaded instance I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:\mydb.db' with class loader WebappClassLoader
context: /Myapp
delegate: false
repositories:
/WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@482923
, see the next exception for details.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at myapp.Myapp.init(Myapp.java:88)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'C:\mydb.db' with class loader WebappClassLoader
context: /Myapp
delegate: false
repositories:
/WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@482923
, see the next exception for details.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\mydb.db.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
... 28 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database C:\mydb.db.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
... 28 more
```

I tried also to delete the db.lck file before trying to create the new connection but this file is locked by the tomcat and cannot be deleted.
Also shutting down all derby system by using: DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");

results in the correct exception but when the application creates the new connection, there is the same error of multiple access.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: PLEASE don't delete the db.lck file! It is there to save you from corrupting your database by having two copies of the Derby engine accessing the database simultaneously without coordination.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you need to modify the content of the `context.xml` file.

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/testDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" username="classiccars" password="classiccars"
            driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
            url="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Nakshatra\.myeclipse\derby\myeclipse"/>
</Context>


   Note:you need to log on as an Administrator if you use Windows 7 OS.
   http://www.mytechguide.org/106/how-to-log-on-as-administrator-in-windows-7/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after altering context path for Tomcat 8.0.
What really helped my - Eclipse reboot.